# sql query with many to many relationship

Tags: sql

We have many-to-many Relationship and these are the details for the same and its non-hierarchical data.

For a User name test 1 >> find Team  >> And the find others Members of the Team

```
 Table Team (Team Table) 
    Id Name 
    1  Ninja
    2  Maverick
    3  Transformer

 Table User (User Table)
    Id Name Email
    1  test1 test1@test.com
    2  test2 test2@test.com
    3  test3 test3@test.com

 Table Team_USER_Map (User Map)
    ID User_Id Team ID
    1  1       1
    2  1       2
    3  2       3
    4  2       1
    5  3       1
    6  3       2
    7  3       3
```

**Problem Statement**:

Depending upon the User Name, I need to find all other's user for same Team.

So for user name = 'test1', I need to  find the Team its belongs and other user belonging to same team.

Comment: Please add the query you are stuck with

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  DECLARE @Name as nvarchar (50)      
  SET @Name = 'test1'

    SELECT u.Name as UserName, u.Email, t.Name as TeamName
    FROM Team as t INNER JOIN Team_USER_Map as tum ON t.Id = tum.Team_ID 
    INNER JOIN User as u ON u.Id = tum.User_Id 
    WHERE u.Name LIKE @Name OR tum.Team_ID = 
    (
      SELECT t.Id 
      FROM Team as t INNER JOIN Team_USER_Map as tum ON t.Id = tum.Team_ID 
      INNER JOIN User as u ON u.Id = tum.User_Id 
      WHERE u.Name LIKE @Name 
    )
```

I think that is what you want to achieve.
The first part of `WHERE` clause is easy because it returns the user with it's name.

In second part, you must use *SELECT WITHIN SELECT* statement to get all users which belong to team of user of typed name.

I hope it's helpful and clear enough.

Good luck!